# Darcs push fails for no apparent reason between Windows and Linux using VMware

Tags: vmware, darcs

I have a strange Darcs issue here.

I'm running a VM with a Linux guest OS and a Windows host OS. I've set up `/mnt` as a "shared folder"; any files placed here are actually stored in a folder on the host OS. Among other things, this causes all files to have their permissions set to `666 root,root`. (Naturally, Windows doesn't support Unix-style file modes.)

Here's what happened:

- `cd /mnt/some-random-folder`
- `darcs init`
- `cd ~/some-random-folder`
- `darcs pull /mnt/some-random-folder`
- Create a few files
- `darcs add` the files
- `darcs record`

So far, everything works fine. But now...

```
user1:~/some-random-folder> darcs push
Pushing to "/mnt/some-random-folder"...
Sun Jan 20 12:11:50 GMT 2013  User1
* Update dependencies.
Shall I push this patch? (1/1)  [ynW...], or ? for more options: y
darcs: ./_darcs/tentative_pristine-0: rename: permission denied (Permission denied)
Apply failed!
```

Erm... what the heck just happened??

(And, more to the point, how do I make it stop happening and actually *work*?)

I tried using `cp` to synchronise the repos, thinking maybe the problem was that I started with a totally empty repo with no patches. That changes the error message (now it can't open `_darcs\index` - permission denied), but it still doesn't actually work.

**Edit:** Darcs 2.8.1 release.

Comment: Do you have an virus scanner that might be opening files after they are created?

Comment: Neither the guest nor the host have any kind of AV software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having played with this further, it appears that accessing files on the host OS from the guest OS does all sorts of strange things. Stuff like, I delete a file, `ls` tells me the file is gone, but when I try to write to that file, it says it can't because it already exists. Unmount and remount the filesystem and the problem goes away.

In short, I think this is probably nothing to do with Darcs at all, and is just the VMware drives being strange / buggy.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions can be a bit tricky.  It's worth checking to see if all file in that /mnt/some-random-folder really are writable by everybody.

I suspect this is not the ideal forum for this sort of question because it will likely involve a lot of back-and-forth chat to figure out what's going on. How about the darcs-users mailing list, or the #darcs IRC channel instead?

Comment: It's impossible to set the permissions to anything else; the driver has them hard-coded. But you're probably right about trying IRC...